# 3 Circles, 1 Mile apart, In the shape of a 3 circled venn diagram, How much area does it cover

Tags: geometry

3 Instances of effect, perfectly circular, with a radius of 1 mile.

I believe that the formation which covers the most ground, without leaving any gaps, would be that of a 3 circled venn diagram.

My questions is twofold, is this inital presumption correct, or is there a better formation; And either way what would the resulting area of effect be.

Thank you for your assistance.

**REPHRASED "NO GAPS" CONDITION:** The centers of the three circles form a triangle $\triangle ABC$.  The "no gaps" condition is that all points in $\triangle ABC$ are also in the union of the interiors of the three circles.

Comment: "3 circled venn diagram" is not a uniquely defined object, and "without leaving any gaps" is not clearly defined either.

Comment: You need to define what configurations are allowed. To cover the most area you want to minimize the overlap area.  A chain of three circles, each just overlapping the next, has very little overlap.  Does that "leave no gaps?"  Clearly if all three circles overlap you want the common area to be as small as possible, which eliminates one region from the Venn diagram.

Comment: Had not thought about doing them in a straight line, I'd like the area for the original diagram please. I'll do the math for the other one now

Comment: In relation to leave no gaps, this is part of a battle simulation, and the effect of having the three circles in a pyramid, or similar configurations would 'leave gaps' inside the area. Basically trying to avoid a war on two fronts.

Comment: It is clear what the OP meant, though the original wording was indeed shaky.  See the rephrased condition I have appended.

Comment: @MarkFischler:  your formulation of the no gaps condition still allows the three circles to be in line.  Although circles A and C do not touch, the whole segment AC is covered by at least one of the three circles.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define the arrangement, then answer the second question of what the covered area is, and finally argue that this is the largest possible area given circles of radius 1 and the "no gaps" condition.

**Define the arrangement:** Label the centers of the three circles $A, B, C$. Let these centers form an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$, such that the center $O$ of $\triangle ABC$ lies on all three circles; thus $OA = OB = OC = 1$. Note that in that case the side $s$ of the eqilateral triangle is $\sqrt{3}$ and that for any equilateral triangle with side greater than $\sqrt{3}$, the center would lie outside the union of the three circles, violating the "no gaps" condition.

**Find the area:** All three circles meet at $O$. Any two circles, say $A$ and $B$, meet at a second point distinct from $O$.  Let $C'$ be the second meeting point of $A$ and $B$,  and similarly define $B'$ and $A'$ as the second meeting points of circles $(A,C)$ and $(B,C)$ respectively. And let $A''$ be the midpoint of line segment $BC$ and similarly for $B''$ and $C''$.

In triangle $ABC$ the medians meet at a point $\frac23$ of their length from the vertices, and that is point $O$.  So $AOA''A'$ form a straight line and $AO =1$ since it is the radius of cercle $A$, so $OA'' = \frac12$.  And since by SSS $\triangle BOC \cong \triangle BA'C$, $A'A'' = \frac12$.  Then $OA'=1$ which establishes that $\triangle BOA'$ is equilateral with side $1$.  Similarly for the other five triangles sharing a vertex at $O$.

So the area covered is that of the regular hexagon $AC'BA'CB'$ of side length $1$, plus three times the area of circular wedge $C'AB'$ (one wedge in each of three triangles). The central angles of those segments are $240^\circ$. Thus the covered ground is given by 
$$
G = 3 \left(\frac23 \pi 1^2\right) + 6\left(\frac12\cdot 1\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 2\pi + 3\sqrt{3}/2\approx 8.881
$$

**Is this area maximal?** Clearly the center $O$ of $\triangle ABC$ must lie on the intersection of three circles in a maximal solution:

- If it lies on the interior of a circle, then one can improve the solution by moving the center of that circle further away.
- If it lies on the intersection of two circles (say $A$ and $B$) and outside the third, then drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$ and one direction along this line lies inside the triangle yet outside the three circles.
- If it lies outside two of the circles and on the third, then extend the radius passing through $O$ and you encounter points lying inside the triangle yet outside the three circles.

So we need consider only arrangements where the three centers of circles themselves lie on a circle, centered at $O$. This is a two-parameter optimization problem (the three possible angles between the lines $OA, OB, OC$ add to $2\pi$) and the maximum is indeed attained where the three angles are all equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the centers on an equilateral triangle.  If there is a point in common to all three circles you get a figure like the below.  The drawing is scaled up by a factor of $3$.   $g,h,i$ are all $1$ and the distance between the centers is $\frac {3 \sqrt 5}4 \approx \frac 53$  The overlap area is six [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) with area $\frac 12(\frac \pi 3 - \sin \frac \pi 3 )$ or total area $3(\frac \pi 3 - \frac {\sqrt 3}2)\approx 0.54$  The covered area is then $3\pi$ minus this

[image]

Comment: Note that either this answer is incorrect or my answer of $2\pi+3\sqrt{3}/2$ is incorrect.

Comment: Aha -- in the above solution, the wedges have angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ not $\frac{\pi}{6}$.  WHen this change is made, our two solutions match; the result is $3\pi - 3(\frac{\pi}{3} - \sin \frac{\pi}{3}) = 2\pi + 3\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @MarkFischler:  you are right.  Corrected.  Thanks.  It seemed way too small.